# looking for a way to detect javascript disabled using PHP (don't want to use noscript in html)

Tags: php, javascript

I want to find out whether the user have javascript enabled or not and I don't want to use the no script tag in HTML because I don't want the user to download extra scripts of both the JavaScript and the no script tag..

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: The only way you can see if javascript is available is try to run some javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to request a php page where you can set a cookie which will be used as flag for JS activation. In js script you can check for existance of cookie if it is set it means user has JS enabled

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not something you can do. PHP code typically fully executes before the browser renders any code at all.

The disabling of Javascript in the browser is not reported to PHP in the initial header request. The closest you can do is to use Javascript to make an AJAX call to PHP to detect for the presence of Javascript. If the callback fails, then you can assume it is disabled.

Similar question: [Can php detect if javascript is on or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172417/can-php-detect-if-javascript-is-on-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

```
test.php

<script>
//// query string
if(/[?&]js=1/g.test(window.location.href) == false)
    window.location.href += (window.location.href.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "js=1";
//// OR session cookie
if(document.cookie.search(/(^|;)js=1/) == -1) {
     document.cookie = "js=1; path=/";
     document.location.reload();
}
</script>

<?php
$_GET["js"];
////
$_COOKIE["js"];
?>
```

There's tons of ways to do this. Set a cookie on the client side with JavaScript, then reload the page, or do the above and add a query string to the URL. PHP can check the cookie or query string and set a session variable saying this user has JS enabled.